# How do I recall data (input into an html form) on another html page?

Tags: php, html, web

Here's the low-down:

I have an HTML page with a form I've created. Not sure if it matters, but I will say that the information is validated using HTML, not PHP. When users submit their information, it is sent to a PHP script where the information is sent to me in an email. That PHP script then redirects to an HTML "THANK YOU" page.

It is on this thank you page that I want to recall their information and "echo" it on the page so that they can then print it out.

How would I go about doing this and what coding would I use? I'm versed in HTML, but just now learning PHP, so detail is appreciated.

Below is an example of my coding:

HTML PAGE WITH FORM:

```
                            <form id="contact-form" action="contact-form_emailer.php" method="post">
                            <table width="497" border="0" id="table-contact">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="form-header">Contact Us</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="required-notice">Fields marked with a <font color="#e3202a">*</font> are required.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item">Date:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" disabled><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('date').value = (new Date()).format("mmmm dd, yyyy");</script></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item">Time:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="time" name="time" disabled><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('time').value = (new Date()).format("h:MM tt");</script></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item">First Name:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td> 
                                    <td><input type="text" min="2" size="40" name="fname" required></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item">Last Name:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" min="2" size="40" name="lname" required></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item" style="vertical-align:top;" rowspan="2">Preferred Method of Contact:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td>
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="method-of-contact" value="email" required checked>Email</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="method-of-contact" value="phone" required>Phone</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item">Phone:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td>
                                    <td><input type="tel" pattern="...-...-...." placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" size="40" name="phone" required></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item">Email:<font color="#e3202a">*</font></td>
                                    <td><input type="email" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com" size="40" name="email" required></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="form-item" style="vertical-align:top;">Message:</td>
                                    <td><textarea cols="31" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message here." name="message"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                      </form>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
    <?php 


//Email Content

$to = "My.Email";  //<-----Email Address to which form is emailed

$email_subject = "New CONTACT Form Submission from $fname $lname";

$email_body = 'The following information was submitted using the CONTACT form.'.
"Date: $date \n ".
"Time: $time \n ".
"First Name: $fname \n ".
"Last Name: $lname \n ".
"Preferred Method of Contact: $method-of-contact \n ".
"Phone: $phone \n ".
"Email: $email \n ".
"Message: $message \n ";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body);


//Redirect to the CONFIRMATION page
//header('Location: contact-form_submit.html');

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
header('Location: contact-form_submit.html');
} else {
    die('Unfortunately there was a problem submitting your form. Please try again or       contact us via email or telephone.');
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use method=POST in your HTML form, so the contents are available in the `$_POST` array in PHP. Do a `var_dump($_POST);` to view your data. The value of email is available in `$_POST['email']`.

Please note that HTML does not *validate* the data. Sure, some browsers may honor your HTML attributes, and maybe some JavaScript validates the fields, but you must **always assume** that data you get from users can be malicious.

Comment: Well I guess i missread your question. Please do not tell me that you have super-globals enabled... In any case, either you can just write the confirmation on the same page, or you can pass along any values you need for the next page in the redirection URL.

Comment: What is the purpose of the var_dump($_POST) ?

I use $_POST and all I get is "undefined index." How do I avoid that?.

Comment: Do I put the $_POST in contact-form_emailer.php or on my THANK YOU page?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. The first is to pass the parameters in the url you are redirecting the user.

```
contact-form_submit.php?param1=value1&param2=value2...
```

And in the page you redirect you use php and `$_GET['param1'] , $_GET['param2']` to have your values. See that the page you redirect to is a php one and not an html one, because it has php code in it.

The second one is to echo the entire page instead of redirecting.

P.S By redirecting I'm referring to the header() function.